# Outputting a PDF file using Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I want to open a file using a servlet and JSP.

I make this code in my JSP page:

```
function action_consultation(grid, record, row, col) {
    var url = "<c:url value='/printer'/>?method=consultDoc&guid=" + record.get('id');
    window.open(url);
}
```

And I develop a servlet which is responsible for opening a file in the PDF format.

This is my servlet code:

```
public class PrinterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PrinterServlet.class);
    private static final String URL_METHOD = "method";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6079308419049730421L;

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String methodName = request.getParameter(URL_METHOD);
        System.out.println("    ::: ---method --------- =" + methodName);

        try {
            if ("consultDoc".equals(methodName)) {

                this.consultDoc(request, response);
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    protected void consultDoc(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        DossierJuridiqueManager dossierJuridiqueManager = (DossierJuridiqueManager) PortalUtil.getBean(DossierJuridiqueManager.managerid);
        byte[] file = new byte[1024];
        file = dossierJuridiqueManager.consultDoc1(request, response, null, request.getParameter("guid"));

        if ((file != null) && (file.length > 0)) {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setContentLength(file.length);

            try {
                ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                ouputStream.write(file, 0, file.length);
                ouputStream.flush();
                ouputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But when I run my application and when I call the function which will open the PDF file I get this error:

```
content type = application/pdf
fileName = testt.pdf
content Size = 287129.0
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:378)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
    at com.dq.foprodex.web.testServlet.PrinterServlet.consultDoc(PrinterServlet.java:66)
    at com.dq.foprodex.web.testServlet.PrinterServlet.service(PrinterServlet.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:216)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:460)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:373)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there a faster way to output a PDF file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591549/is-there-a-faster-way-to-output-a-pdf-file)